# it is possible to change title colors of TTTableMessageItem(Three20)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, three20

when i create instance of TTTableMessageItem, i only can access imageURL,caption,title etc. it is possible to change title colors of  TTTableMessageItem(Three20)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it takes a bit of work (and unfortunately it also takes some experience with Three20 to figure it out).

First, the background:

When you create a `TTTableMessageItem`, Three20 will later create a table cell of type `TTTableMessageItemCell`.  (See the code in `-[TTTableMessageDataSource tableView:cellClassForObject:]` in the Three20UI project.)

So if you look at the source code of the class `TTTableMessageItemCell` (also in the same project), you'll see that it has a property called `titleLabel`.  In the function `- (UILabel*)titleLabel` which creates that label, it sets `_titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]`.

So this gives us the information we need to figure out how to change the title color: You need to find a way to change the `titleLabel.textColor` property of the `TTTableMessageItemCell` instance.  There are a couple of approaches you can take.

The way which is easier, but arguably not quite as clean (but not really that bad), is to create your own table delegate class -- a subclass of `TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate` -- and then implement `-[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]` in your subclass.  In that function, change the titleLabel's textColor.  To take this approach:

- Create your own table view delegate class -- a subclass of `TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate`.  For example, here is `MyDelegate.h`:

  ```
  @interface MyDelegate : TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate
  @end
  ```

  And here is `MyDelegate.m`:

  ```
  @implementation MyDelegate

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
          forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
      if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TTTableMessageItemCell class]]) {
          TTTableMessageItemCell* messageCell = (TTTableMessageItemCell*)cell;
          messageCell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      }
  }

  @end
  ```
- In your table view controller (your subclass of `TTTableViewController`), override `createDelegate`:

  ```
  - (id <UITableViewDelegate>) createDelegate {
      return [[[MyDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
  }
  ```

The other approach, which is perhaps a little cleaner but takes more work, is to subclass `TTTableMessageItem` and `TTTableMessageItemCell`; in your `TTTableMessageItemCell` subclass, change the title color (e.g. by overriding `-[titleLabel]`); then subclass `TTListDataSource` or `TTSectionedDataSource`; in the subclass, override `-[tableView:cellClassForObject:]`; and when you are passed an instance of your `TTTableMessageItem` subclass, return an instance of your `TTTableMessageItemCell` subclass.  Whew!  What this gets you is code reuse: *Any* table can return an instance of your `TTTableMessageItem` subclass and get an appropriately colored title, rather than the above technique which is a bit of a hack because it puts the cell color knowledge in the table view delegate, which isn't really the right place for it.  But as you can see, for something simple like just changing the color, this is a lot of hoops to jump through.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your explanation. it is so useful. i solved problem with using TTTableMessageItemCell. but when i use TTTableMessageItemCell, i cant select any row. didSelectObject method does not work when i click the cell. Before, i was set URL for TTTableMessageItem. does TTTableMessageItemCell support URL like TTTableMessageItem ?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  URLs and didSelectObject should work fine -- just set the URL in the TTTableMessageItem that you created, and that should cause the TTTableMessageItemCell to use that URL and be clickable.